# How to fix the "template0clear" does not exist when trying to restore or create a database in odoo 15?

Tags: postgresql

I want to restore one of my database by using the backup zip file, but the issue is any time I try to restore it or even create a new database I have the following error `template database "template0clear" does not exist`. I know really know if there is any database named `"template0clear"` in postgresql but I do know that the template0 and template1 databases do exist in my postgres. I also check the database config in my odoo file but nothing to signal as well. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: As I said, you need to describe how exactly you took the backup, how exactly you are restoring it and the exact error message. No screen shots, please.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I finally found the root cause of the issue in reality there was a variable in my odoo.conf file named db_template and it was equal to template0clear and it should be template0 only. Now it is working fine. Thanks a lot @LaurenzAlbe